# Warehouse Attributes model

Tags: oracle10g

i am giving a training project for building a schema the following is the question all i would like to ask you guys is i am not sure what attributes would come in the table please see the problem below...

create one new company and attach 10 attributes to the company. the company has two warehouses one in Torrance and another in Costa mesa. each warehouse should have 10 attributes. the company sells 100 products and services. each product and services should have 10 attributes. the company received orders. the orders should have HEADERS and Lines (am not sure what these are). each headers and lin should have 10 attributes. there should be a table for quantity on hand. the quantity on hand will increase once the warehouse receives good.

please i only want some hints or clues on what attributes would generally come in this highlighted tables. 
thanks for help in advance guys....

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving training, or receiving training?

**If you're giving training...**

...I would suggest you reconsider. I would want my money back if the instructor for a course I was taking did not have intimate knowledge of the topic at hand, and the ability to solve any problem in the course material easily.

**If you're receiving...**

...I would suggest you read over the material harder and try to formulate your own solution. You aren't going to get much out of your training if we solve your problems for you.

Comment: i am sooo sorry for the typo their there i was taking training and am new to oracle i really appreciate your concern and indeed your are right after posting this question i had searching many books and finally got all my answers also i am done with the assignment. i am really sorry to post such queries sorry and hope you would keep supporting me in future. thanking you for your time..